# Elasticsearch won't start after upgrade to 7.16.2

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

Due to log4j2 commotion, I upgraded elasticsearch from 7.14 to 7.16.2 but since then I can start elasticsearch. When I run systemctl status elasticsearch.service I get this error. How can I fix this? I am running this on ubuntu 20.04 with daemon. :(

these are command I ran to upgrade elastic search after stopping service. Did I do something wrong in process?

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch

sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
systemd-entrypoint[3776]: For complete error details, refer to the log at /var/log/elasticsearch/test.log
systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Comment: what does the log file say ? systemd-entrypoint[3776]: For complete error details, refer to the log at /var/log/elasticsearch/test.log

Comment: attach two logs here: journalctl -u  elasticsearch.service
cat /var/log/elasticsearch/test.log

Comment: found issue. it was due to plugin I was using for elastic search. I had to update it as well. :(